# How to modify a transfer function of an ERC20 token so that it takes a fee equal to 0.0004 ether for every token transfer

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20, openzeppelin

As I understand I should make transfer function payable but it says "Overriding function changes state mutability from "payable" to "nonpayable".

Answer (score 3):

Solidity currently (v0.8) doesn't allow overriding non-payable methods (e.g. the OpenZeppelin [transfer()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L113) function) to `payable`. So this approach won't work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MyT") {
    }

    // cannot override non-payable function to payable
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) override public payable returns (bool) {
    }
}
```

The [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard doesn't say anything about the `transfer()` function being payable - it doesn't explicitly allow nor disallow it.

---

There are two ways to define a `payable` `transfer()` function in your case:

1. Create a local fork of the OpenZeppelin `ERC20.sol` contract, as well as its dependencies, and change the declaration of their `transfer()` function to `payable`. Then you can override it in a child contract and implement a custom fee.
2. Implement the ERC20 standard from scratch in your contract without using OpenZeppelin. Then you'll be able define a custom `transfer()` function with the `payable` modifier.